# Autofit row height when cell value changes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to autofit the height of certain rows within a worksheet whenever the value of a certain cell changes. The value is selected from a dropdown list.

I've been successful in resizing the height through a button (Form Control) that has a macro assigned to it. Code below:

```
Sub ResizeHeight()
    Range("C11:F26").Rows.AutoFit
End Sub
```

I'm having issues connecting this to the event of a cell ("C5") changing. I tried embedding the macro onto the worksheet code (as shown below) so that it is triggered whenever the cell value changes, but this doesn't work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("D5")) Is Nothing Then
        Call ResizeHeight
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the cell `C5` or `D5`?

Comment: Not really necessary to have the `Target.Worksheet.` part of `Target.Worksheet.Range("D5")`. I would also ask why make a whole second function for a single line operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `Not` in your `If` statement, and this can be simplified to the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D5")) Is Nothing Then
        Me.Rows("11:26").AutoFit
    End If
End Sub
```

Or if you prefer to keep `ResizeHeight` as a separate subroutine, replace

```
Me.Rows("11:26").AutoFit
```

with

```
ResizeHeight
```

noting that the `Call` statement is unnecessary, and there is an implicit `ActiveSheet` in `ResizeHeight`.